# Catch Exception in a Runnable method

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, runnable, executorservice

I am searching a way to catch an `NullPointerException` in a `Runnable` class.
I have this method called by `run` :

```
private void cooccurrence(int contextIndex, int targetIndex) {
        try {
            Double old_value = X.get(contextIndex, targetIndex);
            X.set(contextIndex, targetIndex, old_value + 1);
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            X.growData(X.nz_length + 1);
            X.addItem(contextIndex, targetIndex,  1);
        }
}
```

and I have this code in another class which call a class `ThreadForX implements Runnable` :

```
final BlockingQueue<JSONObject> queue = new
ArrayBlockingQueue<>(5000000);
int json_object_in_queue = 0;

ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

DMatrixSparseTriplet X = new DMatrixSparseTriplet(200000,200000,0);

JSONObject inQueue_jsonObject;
while ((inQueue_jsonObject = queue.poll()) != null) {
        Runnable readTweet = new ThreadForX(contextLenght, inQueue_jsonObject, X, final_vocabulary);
        pool.execute(readTweet);
}
pool.shutdown();
while (!pool.isTerminated()) { }
```

As you can see, the `NullPointerException` is really important to add an item so I need the values of `contextIndex` and `targetIndex`

Comment: You should never have to catch a `NullPointerException`. Just write code that ensures it never happens.

Comment: That's crazy, trying to catch a NullPointerException. Closing as a duplicate because your question just means that you don't yet understand this exception fully enough.

Comment: Let me tell you why I do this :
EJML `DMatrixSparseTriplet` need to know the number of non-zero value at first.
Then, you can grow the size of non value element and add an item. (Actually it is a `nz_data` is a `Element[]`.
BUT i can't know the number of non-zero value at first. That's why I to get/set and if it's failed because it doesnt exist then I grow and add non-zero item.